# How to draw every line with same gradient in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to draw multiple line with a same gradient, but in my code, the second stroke affects the first line.
Does anyone know how to make it? Thank you very much.

```js
function drawOnLoad() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycvs");
  
  var str = canvas.getContext("2d")
  var str_gradient = str.createLinearGradient(7, 7, 300, 150);
  str_gradient.addColorStop(0, "yellow");
  str_gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "blue");
  str_gradient.addColorStop(1, "red");
  str.strokeStyle = str_gradient;
  str.lineWidth = "7"
  str.beginPath()
  str.moveTo(7, 7)
  str.lineTo(300, 150)
  str.stroke()

  var str2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var str2_gradient = str2.createLinearGradient(300, 150, 400, 250)
  str2_gradient.addColorStop(0, "yellow")
  str2_gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "blue")
  str2_gradient.addColorStop(1, "red")
  str2.strokeStyle = str2_gradient
  str2.moveTo(300, 150)
  str2.lineTo(400, 250)
  str2.stroke()
}
```

```html
<body onload="drawOnLoad()">
  <canvas id="mycvs" height="1240" width="1240"></canvas>
</body>
```

The way the second line affects the first is more obvious if you delay drawing the second line:

```js
function drawOnLoad() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycvs");
  
  var str = canvas.getContext("2d")
  var str_gradient = str.createLinearGradient(7, 7, 300, 150);
  str_gradient.addColorStop(0, "yellow");
  str_gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "blue");
  str_gradient.addColorStop(1, "red");
  str.strokeStyle = str_gradient;
  str.lineWidth = "7"
  str.beginPath()
  str.moveTo(7, 7)
  str.lineTo(300, 150)
  str.stroke()

  setTimeout(() => {
    var str2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var str2_gradient = str2.createLinearGradient(300, 150, 400, 250)
    str2_gradient.addColorStop(0, "yellow")
    str2_gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "blue")
    str2_gradient.addColorStop(1, "red")
    str2.strokeStyle = str2_gradient
    str2.moveTo(300, 150)
    str2.lineTo(400, 250)
    str2.stroke()
  }, 800);
}
```

```html
<body onload="drawOnLoad()">
  <canvas id="mycvs" height="1240" width="1240"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to make a call to `str2.beginPath()`.

The explanation is that what you call `str` and `str2` are in fact both the same internal object (graphics context), as shown by the edited snippet below (last line that I added).

As a result, what you do to `str2` may influence what you did to the graphics context when you were still calling it `str`.

```js
function drawOnLoad() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycvs");
  
  var str = canvas.getContext("2d")
  var str_gradient = str.createLinearGradient(7, 7, 300, 150);
  str_gradient.addColorStop(0, "yellow");
  str_gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "blue");
  str_gradient.addColorStop(1, "red");
  str.strokeStyle = str_gradient;
  str.lineWidth = "7"
  str.beginPath()
  str.moveTo(7, 7)
  str.lineTo(300, 150)
  str.stroke()

  var str2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var str2_gradient = str2.createLinearGradient(300, 150, 400, 250)
  str2_gradient.addColorStop(0, "yellow")
  str2_gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "blue")
  str2_gradient.addColorStop(1, "red")
  str2.beginPath()
  str2.strokeStyle = str2_gradient
  str2.moveTo(300, 150)
  str2.lineTo(400, 250)
  str2.stroke()
  
  console.log('str2 === str is ' + (str2 === str));
}
```

```html
<body onload="drawOnLoad()">
  <canvas id="mycvs" height="1240" width="1240"></canvas>
</body>
```